# Como organizar um projeto do C++ em estrutura de pastas no Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, diretório

Gostaria de separa o meu código fonte em pastas para ter uma organização melhor no código, agrupando os arquivos em diretórios.

Em geral costuma se ter bastante arquivos .h e .cpp e costumo ir separando as pastas. Sempre usei o netbeans, mas recentemente resolvi testar o Visual Studio.

Ao iniciar o código (coisa pouca, para seguir um tutorial de criação de jogos em SDL), comecei a organizar o fonte em pastas, como eu costumava fazer. No Visual Studio quando eu estou trabalhando com C++ vejo a opção de adicionar filter, para organizar a estrutura de arquivos, mas não vejo a opção de adicionar pastas.

Consigo organizar o código no que visualmente parece ser uma estrutura de pastas, mas quando vou verificar os arquivos estão uma salada, está tudo misturado na raiz do programa. As opções do Menu apenas me permitem Adicionar um filtro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente fica organizado, mas só visualmente, os códigos continuam todos no mesmo lugar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se dentro do visual studio há uma forma de converter esses filtros em pastas, ou como adicionar a pasta pelo visual studio, pois eu acabei por criar as pastas  e reorganizar manualmente quando me dei conta.

Não que eu costume ter arquivos com o mesmo nome, mas nesse ambiente por exemplo isso seria impossível. Além do que eu acho que fica bem bagunçado se for procurar alguma coisa, ou se precisar trocar de IDE no futuro, pois acredito que essa organização lógica não vai ser reaproveitada em outra IDE como Eclipse, Netbeans e etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procure pelo seguinte botão no Solution Explorer (Show all files).

[image: Botão Show all files]

Ele notificará a estrutura do seu projeto, permitindo que você crie pastas para organizar seu projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]